# Rails + jQuery navigation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Есть сайт на рельсах и навигация по сайту полностью на jquery без перезагрузки страниц(не знаю хорошо это или плохо). Все работает, но не так как хотелось бы, код я писал по мере изучения самого языка. 
Есть меню(заказы, магазин..) с активным `"remote: true"`

```
link_to order_index_path, remote: true
link_to shop_index_path, remote: true
```

... или тоже самое, но в цикле:

```
- menu.each do |m|
    - if ((m.parent == 0) && (can? :read, m.access.constantize))
      = link_to eval(m.link), remote: true do
        .menu-btn = m.title
```

В каждом "index.js" присутствует определенный jQuery(ajax) код:

```
$("#main_content").html("<%= j (render 'index') %>")
...
   $(#somebutton).click(function(){
      console.log('help')
   })
...
```

Если я перехожу на нужную мне вкладку используя меню (`link_to order_index_path, remote: true`), то все работает(логично что подключается `index.js`), но если перезагрузить страницу, то jQuery код не работает. Мне приходится **дублировать** код и прописывать его в coffee script или в `application.js`

Подобная ситуация встречается везде.

Например, мне нужно создать новый заказ, для этого я использую модальное окно (с использованием "slide" эффекта) и когда заказ создан, то в  `create.js` отрисовывается только сама таблица, а не `index`

```
<% if !@order.errors.empty? %>
...
<% else %>
  $(".panel .panel-body").html("<%= j (render "ordertable") %>")
  $("#product-modal").modal("hide")
<% end %>
```

Возвращаясь к началу, jQuery код с `$(#somebutton).click` в `order_index_path` после срабатывания `create.js` так-же перестает работать. Далее в `create.js` мне снова приходится дублировать то же самое действие.
И на выходе мы получаем дубликат уже в 3-х вьюхах: `index.js`, `coffeescript(application.js)` и собственно в `create.js(update.js)`

Как быть? Как мне все это оптимизировать?

**Обновление**

Как я написал выше, все работает. Мне хочется оптимизировать код. Я не считаю правильным копировать один и тот же эвент во все вьюхи, которые связаны с index-ами. Как же DRY? При переходе по ссылке подгружается `index.js`, при перезагрузке страниц подгружается `coffee` и `application.js`, но не используется `index.js` и наоборот. Можно как нибудь обойтись например только `coffee`?

Comment: У вас не работает javascript/jquery код в элементах подгруженных динамически через ajax запросы?

Comment: Насчет избавление от дубликатов в assets есть `require`. т.к у вас динамически обновляется контент, используйте события следующим образом `$(document).on('event_name', '.element', function() { });` и это достаточно выполнить при начальной инициализации

Answer (score 1):

> Есть сайт на рельсах и навигация по сайту полностью на jquery без
>   перезагрузки страниц(не знаю хорошо это или плохо).

Воспользуйтесь `turbolinks` для решения вашей задачи

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Статья на русском

https://habrahabr.ru/post/167161/

Пример использования

https://my100brands.com

В качестве прелоадера я воспользовался плагином `NProgress`
http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

`application.coffee` выглядит следующим образом:

```
initDomPage = ->
 # исполнить код при начальной инициализации DOM дерева

 # Прелоадер для Ajax запросов
 $(document).ajaxSend ->
   NProgress.set(0.7).start()

 $(document).ajaxComplete ->
   NProgress.done()

 $(document).ajaxError ->
   NProgress.done()

initPage = ->
 # исполнить код при обновлении страниц и начальной инициализации

$(document).on 'ready', initPage
$(document).on 'ready', initDomPage
$(document).on 'page:load page:restore', initPage
$(document).on 'page:before-change', -> NProgress.set(0.7).start()
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  NProgress.remove()
  NProgress.done()
```